# Seems like SVG can draw an arc easily -- can VML do it on IE 7 and up?

Tags: svg, vml

The following can draw two arcs easily using SVG, and it works on Firefox or Chrome:

sample page: http://jsfiddle.net/j8aN9/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="80" height="80">

<path fill="none" stroke="#41b419" d="M40,5A35,35,0,1,1,5,40.00000000000001" style="stroke-width: 10px; " stroke-width="10"></path>

<path fill="none" stroke="#b5e5a5" d="M5,40.00000000000001A35,35,0,0,1,39.999999999999986,5" style="stroke-width: 10px; " stroke-width="10"></path>

</svg>
```

can VML do that easily too, so that it works even on IE 7 and up?  (can you give an example of drawing such arc like above?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VML equivalent would be something like:

```
<?xml:namespace prefix = rvml ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
<rvml:group style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1000px; HEIGHT: 1000px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" class=rvml coordsize = "10000,10000">
    <rvml:shape style="WIDTH: 1000px; HEIGHT: 1000px" class=rvml coordsize = "1000,1000" filled = "f" stroked = "t" strokecolor = "#41b419" strokeweight = "7.5pt" path = " m400,50 c669,50,838,342,703,575,568,808,232,808,97,575,66,522,50,461,50,400 e">
      <rvml:fill class=rvml></rvml:fill>
      <rvml:stroke class=rvml opacity = "1" miterlimit = "8"></rvml:stroke>
    </rvml:shape>
</rvml:group>
<rvml:group style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 1000px; HEIGHT: 1000px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" class=rvml coordsize = "10000,10000">
    <rvml:shape style="WIDTH: 1000px; HEIGHT: 1000px" class=rvml coordsize = "1000,1000" filled = "f" stroked = "t" strokecolor = "#b5e5a5" strokeweight = "7.5pt" path = " m50,400 c50,207,207,50,400,50 e">
      <rvml:fill class=rvml></rvml:fill>
      <rvml:stroke class=rvml opacity = "1" miterlimit = "8"></rvml:stroke>
    </rvml:shape>
</rvml:group>
```

But I discovered this by using [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw the shape and then getting the markup with developer tools:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("drawing"), 80, 80);
var c1 = paper.path("M40,5A35,35,0,1,1,5,40.00000000000001");
c1.attr({
    fill: "none",
    "stroke": "#41b419",
    "stroke-width": "10"
});
var c2 = paper.path("M5,40.00000000000001A35,35,0,0,1,39.999999999999986,5");
c2.attr({
    fill: "none",
    "stroke": "#b5e5a5",
    "stroke-width": "10"
});
```

Using Raphaël might be a better approach all round if you need to support both IE and SVG capable browsers.

Comment: so using Raphael, we can really draw an Arc... and that's by using simple path like the above?  I was following some example on StackOverflow that has one MoveTo and tons of LineTo, to achieve the effect of an arc -- drawing tons of lines to simulate a part of the circle.

Comment: how do you get the VML like that?  and how do you make the VML into a page by itself?  I put your Raphael code into a page and it really works on IE 7 and 8.  But using Firebug Lite, I can't get the VML like you did, how do you get them?  http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/VML/arc-by-raphael-and-firebug-lite.html   and  http://www.topics2look.com/code-examples/VML/arc-by-raphael.html

Comment: @動靜能量 I used the developer tools in IE8 (hit F12), selected the parent node in the DOM inspector and selected 'Copy InnerHTML'.  I believe the Raphaël `LineTo` and `MoveTo` methods are really just a layer over `path`.

Comment: oh the other solution just use Path too... but have one move to and tons of line to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061318/drawing-centered-arcs-in-raphael-js