# creating a round list in CSS (for a round menubar)

Tags: css

I am really hoping someone can help me. I am trying to create a round menubar in CSS and I've searched and searched for solutions but have found nothing. I know how to create round areas (by setting the radius), and I know how to create a simple straight line menu using `<ul>` & `<li>` but, as said, I want to create a round one.

there is a picture of something alike what I'd love to get working:

[image]

If anyone could help me on this I'd be so thoroughly grateful.

Comment: Post the code you've done so far?

Comment: to be honest, not sure if thats even possible with just pure css

Answer (score 3):

Closest things I know of are these:

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-round-and-round.html

http://codepen.io/tgrant54/pen/lBHwK

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Thanks so much to you both for that. I love both those menus on the links, and I may take a closer look at their coding, they're a little different. I've used the transform function to create a circle ok, but what I want to do hinges on whether or not I can create the <ul> in a circular fashion. However, I've found a jQuery plugin that allows us to position elements along a Bézier curve, I think this is where I'll head. I'm gonna learn about javascript and jquery before too long. thanks so much for your time and efforts :-) the link is http://jcurvy.com/index.html ... have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This menu looks almost like Path's Button.

You can find the link to Path's Button [here](http://www.redeyeoperations.com/blog/path-fly-out-menu-css3/web-tutorials/).

You just need to modify it a bit so the menu displayed in full sphere.

Comment: I can't believe it's taken me so long to not-remember any longer about having posted this...I got busy doing other things but I'm now back to the web design challenge, so I'll look at your comments soon and respond to. thanks so much for your time, :-)

Comment: I really like that menu, but I've decided to buy one (for $3), from codecanyons.com, thanks so much for the tips, best wishes

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you really want to be doing in pure CSS.

You may be able to make circle shapes with `border-radius`, but you're not actually making a circular object -- it's still a regular box shape as far as the browser is concerned, just with the corners rounded off. This has absolutely no bearing at all on your ability to do anything else to do with circles or curves in CSS.

Yes, it's *possible* to do something along the lines you're after, by putting every character into its own element, and styling each of them with a specific position, but that's going to be painful, inflexible, and difficult to work with. If you really want to do this, there's a [code generator you could try out here](http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/), but I'd say you're barking up the wrong tree.

If you want to do this kind of thing properly, what you really need to be thinking about is doing it in graphical format, using either Canvas or SVG, plus plenty of javascript code.

I'd suggest looking into a JS library like Raphael for this; there are people who have tried similar things already using Raphael, which may help you -- see here, for example: [Radial Pie Menu With Raphael JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429990/radial-pie-menu-with-raphael-js)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't believe it's taken me so long to not-remember any longer about having posted this...I got busy doing other things but I'm now back to the web design challenge, so I'll look at your comments soon. thanks so much for your time, :-)