# Donut / Radial Chart with Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

Im a beginner to Raphael. Can anyone show me how I can do a donut/radial chart, with animation, similar to these.

http://dribbble.com/shots/670348-Segment-Graphs

Im working at it now. So far Ive got this far. I will update as I make progress. My sumbling block right now is animating a change in color for the outer ring.

```
window.onload = function () {

    // Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
    var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

    // Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
    var circle1 = paper.circle(50, 40, 40);

    var circle2 = paper.circle(50, 40, 20);

    circle2.attr("fill", "#fff");
    circle2.attr("stroke", "#fff");

    circle1.attr("fill", "#336699");
    circle1.attr("stroke", "#fff");

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Credits:**
On the [raphael website](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html) there is an example that uses arcs. There is another question on stackoverflow with a similar topic: [drawing centered arcs in raphael js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061318/drawing-centered-arcs-in-raphael-js). The accepted answer there has a simplified and commented version of the most important parts of the code, plus there is a jsfiddle link showing the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Bzdnm/2/

*So what I did*: I took the code from the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061318/drawing-centered-arcs-in-raphael-js), combined it with [eve](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/eve), another javascript library made by the [creator](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/) of RaphaelJS and what I got was this: http://jsfiddle.net/cristighenea/aP7MK/

At a glance:

1.after the arc is created we rotate it 180 degrees and begin animating it:

```
theArc.rotate(180, 100, 100).animate({
    arc: [100, 100, amount, 100, 40]
}, 1900, function(){
    //animation finish callback goes here
});
```

2.using eve we bind an event to *raphael.anim.frame.**

3.each time the event is fired we update the text in the middle with the new value of the arc

If you have any questions let me know

Comment: hi. I have a follow up question about this. Can you maybe answer it for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882577/raphael-chart-placement-relative-to-containing-div

Comment: Thank you @Chris Ghenea, I saw a dozen of sample here, and it was using a somewhat "messy" code to render the arc from a different starting angle. Your solution is the cleanest. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! Helped a lot when developing our [Donut Chart lib](https://github.com/xtremelabs/xl-donut_chart-javascript). Hopefully I can find the time to polish it off some more.