# Raphael JS - Animating a semi-circle along its path

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have a gauge / dial type level to be animated in my app. The needle and dial will automatically get updated when values change. The code I have got to works OK for small changes, but when it has bigger changes the animation does not go along the path of the semi-circle.

The code I have is like this: (the interval is just for testing purposes)

```
var rad = Math.PI / 180;
var getCurvePath = function(cx, cy, r, startAngle, endAngle) {
    var x1 = cx + r * Math.cos(-startAngle * rad),
        x2 = cx + r * Math.cos(-endAngle * rad),
        y1 = cy + r * Math.sin(-startAngle * rad),
        y2 = cy + r * Math.sin(-endAngle * rad);

    return ["M", x1, y1, "A", r, r, 0, +(endAngle - startAngle > 180), 0, x2, y2];
};

var zeroAngle = 197, fullAngle = -15,baseAngle = 199,
    r = Raphael('level');

var level = r
    .path(getCurvePath(150, 150, 75, zeroAngle, baseAngle))
    .attr({
        'stroke': '#FF0000',
        'stroke-width': '11px'
    });

window.setInterval(function() {
    var ratio = Math.random();
    var newLevelAngle = (zeroAngle - fullAngle) * ratio;
    level.animate({
        'path': getCurvePath(150, 150, 75, newLevelAngle, baseAngle)
    }, 1000, 'bounce');
}, 2000);
```

I have set up a JS Fiddle here so you can see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Rfd3v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer here sorted my problem out: 
[drawing centered arcs in raphael js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061318/drawing-centered-arcs-in-raphael-js)

I needed to adapt a few things from @genkilabs's answer to suit the level/gauge application. Hopefully this might be helpful to someone else:

```
var arcCentre = { x: 100, y: 100 },
    arcRadius = 50,
    arcMin = 1, // stops the arc disappearing for 0 values
    baseRotation = -100, // this starts the arc from a different point
    circleRatio = 220/360, // I found this helpful as my arc is never a full circle
    maxValue = 1000; // arbitrary        

// starts the arc at the minimum value
var myArc = r.path()
         .attr({
             "stroke": "#f00",
             "stroke-width": 14,
             arc: [arcCentre.x, arcCentre.y, arcMin, 100, arcRadius],
         })
         .transform('r'+ baseRotation + ',' + arcCentre.x + ',' + arcCentre.y);

// set a new value
var newValue = 234; // pick your new value

// convert value to ratio of the arc to complete
var ratio = newValue / maxValue;

// set level
var newLevelValue = Math.max(arcMin, ratio * 100 * circleRatio);
myArc.animate({
    arc: [arcCentre.x, arcCentre.y, newLevelValue, 100, arcRadius]
}, 750, 'bounce');
```