# jQuery Check if String is HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to check if a string is a HTML Tag or not. I've searched in google and tried codes below, but no success:

```
var v = $(string).html() ? 1 : 0;

--or----------------------------------------------

var htmlExpr = new RegExp("/^(?:[^<]*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|#([\w\-]+)$)/");
var v = htmlExpr.test(string) ? 1 : 0;

--or----------------------------------------------

var v = $(string).each(function(){$(this).html();} ? 1 : 0;
```

====

Actually I want to check if the string is an img tag, get the alt attribute of it and if is not (it's a normal non-html string) get the whole of it.

Please help me with this problem...
Thanks

====

Let me show you a true example with all side details...

This is the main function:

```
content.find('a').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        optText = '&nbsp;' + $this.text(),
        ...,
        ...,
        ...;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

in this function, I need to process the "$this.text()" part in the 3rd line.

The text in a tag which we are looking for, sometimes contains a normal string and sometimes includes an img tag. When it is a normal text, I want to put it in optText variable completely; But when it is an img tag, I just want to put it's alt attribute in that variable.

So briefly:

```
$this.text() => NormalText

--or----------------------------------------------

$this.text() => <img src="#" alt="AltText" />
```

So I've changed that function and replaced the "$this.text()" code in the third line with each of these codes:

```
($this.text().html() ? $('img', $this.text()).attr('alt') : $this.text())

--or----------------------------------------------

(htmlExpr.test($this.text()) ? $('img', $this.text()).attr('alt') : $this.text())

[which htmlExpr was defined before...]

--or----------------------------------------------

($this.text().each(function(){$(this).html();}) ? $('img', $this.text()).attr('alt') : $this.text())
```

but none of these codes worked for me...

Now, Can you help me please?!

Comment: Provide a sample string ...

Comment: I've added more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself... It was a logical error...

the point is that when the string is a normal text, we can take it with using `text()`, but when it is HTML we should use `html()` instead, otherwise the `text()` returns `null`...

I've also learned something from you guys... Thank you all very much... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?:

```
var str = "<img alt='hello'>";

if(str.match(/\<img.+\>/)) {
    str = $(str).attr('alt');
}
```

It takes the string, checks if it's an `img` element, and then gets the alt attribute. A simpler way would be to just check for `alt` in the if statement:

```
if($(str).attr('alt')) {
    str = $(str).attr('alt');
}
```

You can also use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) combined:

```
if($(str).is('img') && $(str).attr('alt')) {
    str = $(str).attr('alt');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the last part... It seems to be easier and more clear than the REGEX method.

Comment: I know dude... but there is some time restrictions at the mean time... I'll do it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if it's an image and has an `alt` attribute try this regex:

```
/(?=.*alt=".+")<img.*?\/?>/
```

Quick test:

```
var str1 = '<img src="http://dot.com/test.jpg" alt="test"/>';
var str2 = '<img src="http://dot.com/test.jpg" alt="" />';
var str3 = '<input/>';

console.log(img.test(str1)); //= true
console.log(img.test(str2)); //= false
console.log(img.test(str3)); //= false
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Hgn/)**

```
var samples = ["<img src='#' alt='img1' />","hello","bye","<img src='#' alt='img2' />"];
for(var i = 0, len = samples.length; i < len; i++) {
    if($(samples[i]).length > 0) {
        alert($(samples[i]).attr('alt'));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It does appear to correctly check for img elements and retrieve their alt attributes.

Comment: It is a fashion, as was brought up in that meta discussion. It's not a good fashion though. :P

Comment: I agree, semantics should be at the top. But there's no way here to highlight link. See comment on my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372162/raphael-js-fill-color-along-a-curve. A guy literally forced me to use `kbd`.

Comment: I would have pointed out to the guy there were several links in the post already, if he'd look for them. :)